Laravel ldaprecord ldap_bind_ext(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server
I am using ldap record on my laravel app.
I have the following in my .env file:
LDAP_LOGGING=true
LDAP_CONNECTION=default
LDAP_CONNECTIONS=default

LDAP_DEFAULT_HOSTS="ad01.company.com"
LDAP_DEFAULT_USERNAME="CN=csh_dashboard_ldap,OU=Service Accounts,DC=company,DC=com"
LDAP_DEFAULT_PASSWORD="password!"
LDAP_DEFAULT_PORT=636
LDAP_DEFAULT_BASE_DN="dc=company,dc=com"
LDAP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=20
LDAP_DEFAULT_SSL=true
LDAP_DEFAULT_TLS=false
LDAP_DEFAULT_SASL=false
LDAP_DEFAULT_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION=3

and the following in the /etc/ldap/ldap.conf
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

#BASE   dc=example,dc=com
#URI    ldap://ldap.example.com ldap://ldap-provider.example.com:666

#SIZELIMIT      12
#TIMELIMIT      15
#DEREF          never
TLS_REQCERT hard

# TLS certificates (needed for GnuTLS)
# TLS_CACERT    /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/jh-company.ca.pem


and I get the following error from  php artisan ldap:test

| default    | ✘ No       | CN=csh_dashboard_ldap,OU=Service Accounts,DC=company,DC=com | ldap_bind_ext(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server (-1). Error Code: [-1] Diagnostic Message: (unknown error code) | 320.86ms      |


If i change the following in /etc/ldap/ldap.conf i get a success message:
TLS_REQCERT never

default    | ✔ Yes      | CN=csh_dashboard_ldap,OU=Service Accounts,DC=company,DC=com | Successfully connected. | 291.81ms  

the cert has the following perms:
user@server:/var/www/csh-dashboard$ ls /etc/ssl/certs/jh-company.ca.pem -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Apr 26 09:32 /etc/ssl/certs/jh-company.ca.pem -> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/jh-company.ca.crt


I can also access the ldap server on telnet 636 so i dont think the port is blocked.
Can anyone assist? I am not sure what else to do.

Well, I got it working with the following in the .env file:
LDAP_DEFAULT_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT = "LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_HARD"
